# Nextjs Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div> when using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

There are similar questions posed here and on Google, but none with answers that fit my scenario.

Basically, I want to display a different searchbar in the header, depending on what page I am on. This is nextjs.

But when reloading the page, I get the error in console:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>
```

First thing I tried was

```
const currentPath =  Router.router?.route;

return (
      <div className="sub-bar">
        {currentPath === '/products' && (
          <Search />
        )}
       
        {currentPath === '/baseballcards' && (
          <SearchBaseballCards />
        )}
      </div>
);
```

That generates the error when reloading the page, even if I comment either of them out.

Next thing I tried was the ternary route:

```
      <div className="sub-bar">

        {currentPath === '/baseballcards' ? <SearchBaseballCards /> : <Search />}

      </div>
```

This actually worked but ternary is no good because I only want the search bar on the /products and /baseballcards pages.

Final thing I tried was:

```
  const currentPath =  Router.router?.route;
  let searchbar;

  if (currentPath === '/baseballcards') {
    searchbar = <SearchBaseballCards />
  } 
  else if (currentPath === '/products') {
    searchbar = <Search />
  }
  else {
    searchbar = null;
  }

return (
      <div className="sub-bar">

        {searchbar}

      </div>
);
```

This gives me the original error when reloading the page, so back to square one.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Are you sure the error is because of this component?

Comment: almost positive because if I comment out the search bar(s), the error does not appear on reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than accessing the `Router` object directly with `Router.router?.route`, use the router instance returned by the `useRouter` hook. This will ensure that the rendering between server and client is consistent.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const SearchBar = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const currentPath = router.asPath;

    return (
        <div className="sub-bar">
            {currentPath === '/products' && (
                <Search />
            )}
            {currentPath === '/baseballcards' && (
                <SearchBaseballCards />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: this is the way.